# Delete point in trail Renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was wondering if there would be a way to delete the last couple of positions/indexes of a trail renderer. I am trying to stop the trail render emission after a bullet collision, but the trail renderer always spawns a couple of indexes too much, and I was wondering if there was a way to delete those indexes.

I have tried setting the positions of newer indexes to equal older indexes, and that worked to some extent but not to the extent that I wanted.

```
tR = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
int positions = tR.positionCount;

for (int i = 0; i < vertsToDelete; i++) {
    if (positions - 1 - i - (int)vertsToDelete > 0) {
        tR.SetPosition(positions - 1 - i, tR.GetPosition(positions - 1 - i - (int)vertsToDelete));
    }
}
```

This code works mostly except for certain instances when the positions screw up.  Thats why i think being able to delete an index would make the process much easier.

Comment: You can decrease the `time` property, it removes the vertices from the tail.

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to use one single `GetPositions` call, manipulate the array and write it back completely using one single `AddPositions` call.

In order to alternate the array you could go through a list which allows dynamically changing the amount of elements more easily.

Start by converting the array to a list using [Linq `IEnumerable.ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist)

```
var positions = new Vector3[tr.positionCount];
tr.GetPositions(positions);
var positionsList = positions.ToList();
```

then remove an element by index using [`List<T>.RemoveAt(int index)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAt_System_Int32_)

```
positionsList.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
```

or remove multiple sequential elements using [`List<T>.RemoveRange(int startIndex, int amount)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveRange_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

```
positionsList.RemoveRange(startIndex, amountToRemove);
```

And finally convert it back to the required arrays using [`List<T>.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_ToArray)

```
tR.Clear();
tR.AddPositions(positionsList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still searching for this.
I had an issue just like that, my **Trail Renderer** was drawing some artifact when I used the **Floating Origin** on it (even when I turned emission off, it was like it had a delay on turning off).

After 2 weeks trying many things and searching I solved this in the most ridiculous way:

```
    //I have this at the beginning os my class:
    //public TrailRenderer trailRenderer;

    //and this declared at start:
    //trailRenderer = trailRenderer.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();

    int trailSize = trailRenderer.positionCount;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(trailRenderer.GetPosition(trailSize - 1), (trailRenderer.GetPosition(trailSize - 2)));
    Debug.Log("Distance: " + distance);

    if (distance > 90f)
    {
        trailRenderer.SetPosition(trailSize - 1, trailRenderer.transform.position);
    }
```

This verify the wrong Draw (in my case is just the last point) and get it back to my trail renderer transform, preventing any artifacts my floating origin may cause **if it causes any**. That's way better than use a for to verify every position since I only have an issue with the last one. Just adapt that to your needs :)